# Let $R$ and $S$ be rings of characteristic $0$. If $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic as a ring, then, why $R/7R$ is isomorphic to $S/7S$ as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ and $S$ be rings of characteristic $0$.

If $R$ and $S$ are isomorphic as a ring, then, why $R/7R$ is isomorphic to $S/7S$ as  a ring ?

My try :
Let $φ:R→S$ be an isom and $π: S→S/7S$ be natural projection.
If we could prove $ker(π・φ)＝7S$・・・①, it's done. But I'm having trouble proving ① formally. Another approach is also appreciated.

Comment: What does $R/7R$ and $S/7S$ mean?

Comment: $R$  contains $7$, and $7R$ is ideal of $R$.  $R/7R$ means residue ring. Same for $S$.

Comment: The inclusion $\supseteq$ is obvious. This gives a homomorphism $R/7R\to S/7S$. The other direction $\psi\colon S\to R$ gives a homomorphism $S/7S\to R/7R$, and you can check these are inverses of each other.

Comment: By the way, the characteristic of the rings R and S are irrelevant.